# How is it that a cistern can collect rainfall, but a well cannot, even though both of them are holes?

Tags: water, flow

I imagined that a regular downpour or flood of rain would fall into the well directly, so I did a search on Google and was surprised to find this [answer](https://www.wellguardian.us/does-rainfall-do-anything-for-my-residential-well/#:%7E:text=While%20your%20well%20is%20a,expect%20a%20cistern%20to%20function.&text=With%20less%20rain%2C%20or%20changes,does%20reap%20the%20indirect%20benefits.). But the article didn't make sense other than that the water would seep through the ground and in ten years, it would be at the water table, where it might, perhaps, refill the well. Still, I'm not sure what sets a cistern apart at being able to collect rainwater, since the gravity should be able to pull rain down.

If there is a better SE site for this question, feel free to move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without directing runoff rainwater into an open well it can only catch the rain that lands on its exposed surface area. This could only add a few inches at most in a single rainfall.  A cistern directs runoff from a larger area into it, so it is fed by a much larger area than just the surface area of the tank.

Answer (score 1):

Cisterns are distinguished from wells by their waterproof linings.

A well communicates with the surrounding ground and as such the level of water in the well will equilibrate with the ground water level after water is drawn from or added to the well (e.g., from rainfall).  The cistern is a closed vessel and can fill up as rainfall water is diverted into the cistern; for example, there is no fresh water on the island of Bermuda and fresh water is collected in cisterns from water collected on roofs and routed to cisterns through a vertical pipe from the roof to the cistern.